# How do I pass variables or even text into a text document with a batch command?

Tags: csv, batch-file, variables

I am looking to use a batch command to create a new text document in a specific folder.

```
@echo off
 echo.>"[Path]\[DocName].txt"
```

This allows me to create a document in a specific folder. All thats working great.

Now i am wanting to pass variables/parameters into that text file. How can I pass a variable to populate in the text document i just saved?

additional question, can I do this in a CSV instead of a txt? I only seem to be able to create a txt document.

Comment: a CSV file *is* a textfile - just with another extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo text > file.txt`

Change the text to whatever you want. Change the file name to whatever you want (It doesn't have to be a `.txt` file, you can save it as a `.csv` as you wanted.) If you want to pass a variable into the file,

`echo %var% > file.txt`

Easy as that.

Comment: echo  >"C:\FolderA\DocName.txt" works when I put in text like ABCD -> it passes no problem. but when I try and pass %1 as a variable it doesnt pass.  how do i need to format the variable?

Comment: What is in the `%1` variable? `echo %1 > "C:\FolderA\DocName.txt"` doesn't work?

Comment: @NicholasKnipp If there's nothing in `%1`, the file will be filled with `ECHO is off.`. If there IS something in `%1`, try this: `set var=%1`, then, on the next line, `echo %var% > file.txt`.

Comment: The recommended methods are, `(Echo(%1)>"file.txt"` or `>"file.txt" Echo(%1`. There is certainly no need to define a variable with the existing content of the first argument, when performing such a basic task.

Comment: @Compo It's all the same thing. The method used is up to him.

Comment: @EthanWaldeck, no it isn't, your first example is writing text plus a space character to the file, your second is writing either 1. `ECHO is on.`, 2. `ECHO is off.`, or 3. the content of `%var%` plus a space character.

Comment: Oh, boo-hoo. It's a space. Looks like my answer isn't valid anymore.

Comment: @Ethan: such stray spaces can complicate further processing a lot. (and they are hard to troubleshoot because you "don't see them")

Comment: Also, if you were to read the question fully, it states, "How can I pass a variable to populate in the text document i just saved?" Each of your examples technically overwrites everything in the file, as opposed to populating an existing file. For that you'd need to use the method in my answer or use `>>` instead of `>` for each new entry, _which is wasteful on resources as it has to open, write, and close, for each instance_.

Answer (score 1):

To add several lines of data to a new text file, from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), this is the recommended syntax:

```batch-file
@(
    Echo(%1
    Echo Something before an empty line
    Echo(
    Echo Something after an empty line
)>"[Path]\[DocName].txt"
```

The most important thing to remember, when using this methodology is that any `)` characters to be `Echo`ed must be escaped using a caret, i.e. `Echo This works, (hopefully^).`